# making a function the components of the .agg() in a groupBy statement, produces an AssertionError

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

Please note that you may run this locally only if you already install spark by running the following command. Otherwise replicate the issue on a Databricks cluster which will initialize a spark context automatically.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark =  SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

**dataframe**

```py
spark_dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
                           {'id' : ['001', '001', '001', '001', '001', '002', '002', '002'],
                            'OuterSensorConnected':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
                            'OuterHumidity':[31.784826, 32.784826, 33.784826, 43.784826, 23.784826, 54.784826, 31.784826, 31.784826],
                            'EnergyConsumption': [70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70],
                            'DaysDeploymentDate': [10, 20, 21, 31, 41, 11, 19, 57]}
                           )
spark_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(spark_dataframe)
```

**my issue**

I group by the data by ID and I want to aggregations applied to be in a function. Because the same aggregations are applied in many different applications, so this creates a modularity in the code. The function of the aggregations:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as sql_function

def data_aggregation():
    sql_function.mean("OuterSensorConnected").alias("OuterSensorConnected"),
    sql_function.mean("OuterHumidity").alias("averageOuterHumidity"),
    sql_function.mean("EnergyConsumption").alias("EnergyConsumption"),
    sql_function.max("DaysDeploymentDate").alias("maxDaysDeploymentDate")

spark_dataframe =spark_dataframe .groupBy("id")\
                                 .agg(data_aggregation())
```

The above execution code gives me the following error:

```py
"AssertionError: all exprs should be Column"
```

[image]

*PS: I know that I could make a function the whole groupBy statement. However, this changes from an application to another application, so I wanted modularize only the fixed part which was the columns to aggregate. Is there a way to fix this? If not I can bear with it but I wanna know the why.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to correct the syntax in the agg() command.

```
def data_aggregation():
    expr =[sql_function.mean("OuterSensorConnected").alias("OuterSensorConnected"),
    sql_function.mean("OuterHumidity").alias("averageOuterHumidity"),
    sql_function.mean("EnergyConsumption").alias("EnergyConsumption"),
    sql_function.max("DaysDeploymentDate").alias("maxDaysDeploymentDate")]
    return(expr)

spark_dataframe =spark_dataframe .groupBy("id")\
                                 .agg(*(data_aggregation()))
```

Refer this answer for a better method to modularize your function calls: [pyspark: groupby and aggregate avg and first on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620453/pyspark-groupby-and-aggregate-avg-and-first-on-multiple-columns/62620944#62620944)

If you want to apply your custom function to grouped data, google pandas user defined aggregate function.