# How to count frequency of min and max for all columns from a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe where i am finding out min/max values and count of min/max values for each columns. I am able to select min/max values using:
`df.select([min(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`
I want to have the count of min/max values as well in same dataframe.
Specific output I need:
...*|            col_n            |             col_m            |*...
...*|               xn              |                xm              |*... min(col(coln))
...*| count(col_n==xn) | count(col_m==xm) |*...

Comment: Can you post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,struct,array
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,7,2,11),(1,3,4,12),(1,5,6,13),(1,7,8,14),(2,9,10,15),(2,11,12,16),(2,13,14,17)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
expr=[F.max(coln).alias(coln+'_max') for coln in tst.columns]
tst_mx = tst.select(*expr)
#%%
tst_dict = tst_mx.collect()[0].asDict()
#%%
expr1=( [F.count(F.when(F.col(coln)==tst_dict[coln+'_max'],F.col(coln))).alias(coln+'_max_count') for coln in tst.columns])
#%%
tst_res = tst.select(*(expr+expr1))
```

In the expr, I have just tried out for max function. you can scale this to other functions like min,mean etc., even use a list comprehension for the function list. Refer this answer for such a scaling : [pyspark: groupby and aggregate avg and first on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620453/pyspark-groupby-and-aggregate-avg-and-first-on-multiple-columns/62620944#62620944)
It is explained for aggregate, can also be done to select statement.

Comment: This will give count of entire column. I want count of min/max values in column.

Comment: @Harhaaakr - sorry, just now got it.. can you check now?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for some answer which doesnt involve collect statement (maybe we can use subquery, but dont know how to use it in pyspark).

Comment: ok, not sure about that. Since only you are collecting summary data, the memory shouldnt be a big problem in case of collect.

Comment: Possible answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882894/spark-sql-apply-aggregate-functions-to-a-list-of-columns